# Using `joins()` for the first 4 tables INNER JOIN then a LEFT JOIN for the fifth table- ruby - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm

How to convert this:

```
   SELECT Table1.id FROM Table1
   INNER JOIN Table2 
   INNER JOIN Table3
   INNER JOIN table4
   INNER JOIN Table5
   LEFT JOIN Table6 ON Table6.id = Table5.table6_id
```

Updated example with names:

```
SELECT Student.id FROM Table1
INNER JOIN student_notes ON student_notes.student_id = student.id
INNER JOIN notes ON notes.id = student_notes.note_id
INNER JOIN note_tags ON note_tags.note_id = notes.id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = note_tags.tag_id
LEFT JOIN computer_labels ON computer_labels.id = tags.label_id
```

Into Rails ORM syntax:
something like this, without using raw query

```
Table1.joins(Table2: { Table3: { Table4:  :table5 }})
```

The **left join Table6** in missing how to add it?

Answer (score 1):

For the [`inner joins`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-multiple-level) the syntax is pretty straight forward (assuming that you defined all association in the models correctly):

```
Student
  .select(:id)
  .joins(student_notes: { notes: { note_tags: :tags } })
```

But although `ActiveRecord` has a [`left_outer_joins`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins) method, it is not helpful in this case because you do not want to outer join every table beginning at `students`. Therefore, I would just add the last join manually with the string syntax, like this:

```
Student
  .select(:id)
  .joins(student_notes: { notes: { note_tags: :tags } })
  .joins('LEFT JOIN computer_labels ON computer_labels.id = tags.label_id')
```

Note that you can simplify these joins and other queries when you define additional [`has_many ... through:`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) associations.

Comment: ok, with the left join before computer labels, that's what I was thinking, thanks.

Comment: @spickerman is that last join really a left join? It looks just like an inner join. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @LesNightingill You are right, I accidentally remove the `LEFT JOIN` part while copy'n'pasting. I fixed my answer to address your comment.